# What is the average order of the Dirichlet inverse of the Euler totient function?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, limits

Let $a(n)$ be [the Dirichlet inverse of Euler totient function](https://oeis.org/A023900):

$$a(n) = \sum\limits_{d|n} d \cdot \mu(d)$$

where $\mu(d)$  is [the Möbius function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function).

I can justify but not prove that the limiting ratio is equal to $1$:

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{a(n+1)}{a(n)}=1$$

This suggests that the average order of $a(n)$ is a constant and not a function.

Since [the average order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average_order_of_an_arithmetic_function) of the Möbius function $\mu(n)$ is zero, does it mean that the average order of $a(n)$ is also zero?

$$\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n \le N} a(n)=0$$

Comment: Perhaps for your second claim, previous about the average order of $a(n)$ you are thinking about an argument involving the Möbius function that I don't understand. Thanks.

Comment: You are right that using $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{a(n+1)}{a(n)}=1$ as an argument for claiming that the average order is a constant is flawed. I realized this now. But regarding the second claim about the Möbius function I don't know.

Comment: Which I am saying is that sure that your question is a good question and since your definiton involves the Möbius function, I don't know how I can solve  it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dirichlet generating function of the Euler totient function is

$$F(s) = \frac{\zeta(s-1)}{\zeta(s)},$$

hence the Dirichlet generating function of its Dirichlet inverse is

$$G(s) = \frac{\zeta(s)}{\zeta(s-1)}.$$

We know that $\zeta$ has infinitely many zeros on the critical line and no zeros with real part $\geqslant 1$, hence $G$ has infinitely many poles with real part $\frac{3}{2}$. Therefore the abscissa of convergence of $G$ is $\geqslant \frac{3}{2}$, whence

$$\limsup_{x\to\infty} \frac{\log \lvert A(x)\rvert}{\log x} \geqslant \frac{3}{2}$$

where

$$A(x) := \sum_{n \leqslant x} a(n).$$

It follows that for every $\mu < \frac{3}{2}$ there are infinitely many $N \in \mathbb{N}$ with

$$\Biggl\lvert\sum_{n = 1}^N a(n)\Biggr\rvert > N^{\mu},$$

so the average order of $a(n)$ cannot belong to $o(N^{1/2-\varepsilon})$ for any $\varepsilon > 0$. In particular, it is not a constant.